# How to change the default artifactId of maven-metadata.xml when uploading to bintray

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin, bintray, jcenter, maven-metadata

In my project I've set a custom artifactId for maven POM:

```
install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom {
            project {
              artifactId = moduleProperties.getProperty("module.artifactId")
              ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where moduleProperties is a Properties class that loads a property file.

With this set, the POM file has the [correct artifactId](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/kaichunlin/maven/com/github/kaichunlin/transition/transition/0.8.0/transition-0.8.0.pom) ("core"). However, the generated [maven-metadata.xml](https://bintray.com/artifact/download/kaichunlin/maven/com/github/kaichunlin/transition/transition/maven-metadata.xml) on bintray continues to use Android-Studio module name as artifactId ("transition"). So the question is how do I change the artifactId in maven-metadata.xml?

Here's the gradle code used to push artifact to bintray:

```
/**
 * JCenter publishing logic courtesy of https://www.virag.si/2015/01/publishing-gradle-android-library-to-jcenter/
 */
def siteUrl = 'https://github.com/kaichunlin/android-transition'      // Homepage URL of the library
def gitUrl = 'https://github.com/kaichunlin/android-transition.git'   // Git repository URL
group = "com.github.kaichunlin.transition"                            // Maven Group ID for the artifact

Properties moduleProperties = new Properties()
moduleProperties.load(project.file('module.properties').newDataInputStream())

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        // This generates POM.xml with proper parameters
        pom {
            project {
                packaging 'aar'

                // Add your description here
                name moduleProperties.getProperty("module.pom_name")
                artifactId = moduleProperties.getProperty("module.artifactId")
                description moduleProperties.getProperty("module.desc")
                url siteUrl

                // Set your license
                licenses {
                    license {
                        name 'The Apache Software License, Version 2.0'
                        url 'http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt'
                    }
                }
                developers {
                    developer {
                        id 'kaichunlin'
                        name 'Kai-Chun Lin'
                        email 'kaichun.lin@gmail.com'
                    }
                }
                scm {
                    connection gitUrl
                    developerConnection gitUrl
                    url siteUrl
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classifier = 'sources'
}

task javadoc(type: Javadoc) {
    source = android.sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs
    classpath += project.files(android.getBootClasspath().join(File.pathSeparator))
}

task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives javadocJar
    archives sourcesJar
}

Properties properties = new Properties()
properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())

def test = false

bintray {
    user = properties.getProperty("bintray.user")
    key = properties.getProperty("bintray.apikey")

    configurations = ['archives']
    dryRun = test //Whether to run this as dry-run, without deploying
    publish = !test //If version should be auto published after an upload
    pkg {
        repo = "maven"
        name = moduleProperties.getProperty("module.bintray")
        websiteUrl = siteUrl
        vcsUrl = gitUrl
        licenses = ["Apache-2.0"]
        publish = !test
        version {
            gpg {
                sign = true //Determines whether to GPG sign the files. The default is false
//                passphrase = properties.getProperty("bintray.gpg.password") //Optional. The passphrase for GPG signing'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files aren't named correctly. You have `transition-0.8.0.aar`, so the `artifactId` can't be `core`. If you want everything to be `core`, you need to rename the project, changing the pom is not enough.

Comment: Do you mean that I have to change the Android module name? That would break the stuff I've already uploaded to GitHub

Comment: that's the only way. changing pom only won't help. Not because Bintray, but because Maven. You **must** have the `artifactId` match the file (and the directory) name.

Comment: I see, well at least I don't have to waste time search in futility now.